# Keras - how to set weights to a single layer

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to set the weights of a hidden layer.

I'm assuming layers[0] is the inputs, and I want to set the weights of the first hidden layer so set the index to 1.

`model.layers[1].set_weights(weights)`

However, when I try this I get an error:

`` ValueError: You called `set_weights(weights)` on layer "dense_64" with a  weight list of length 100, but the layer was expecting 2 weights. Provided weights: [ 1.0544554   1.27627635  1.05261064  1.10864937  ... ``

The hidden layer has 100 nodes.

As it is telling me that it expects two weights, is one the weight and one the bias?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keras expects the layer weights to be a list of length 2. First element is the kernel weights and the second is the bias.

You can always call `get_weights()` on the layer to see shape of weights of that layer. `set_weights()` would expect exactly the same.

Comment: It is always a good thing to output shapes, lengths, etc. of the thing you're working with :)

Answer (score 8):

Or you can simply try this

```
model.layers[i].set_weights(some_other_model.layers[i].get_weights())
```